# Get certificate from DSA Private Key

Tags: openssl, certificate

I have a private DSA key in PEM format that contains the following:

```
-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,XXXXXXXXXX

xxxx....
-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and I need to produce a public certificate from this private key.

I can convert it to a public key in the format:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
xxxx....
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

using `openssl dsa -in private-key.pem -pubout` but can't seem to get a certificate from it. My understanding is that the private key contains the certificate *and* additional information, therefore I should be able to extract it somehow.

The format I need is

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxx....
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something?

Comment: I think this is more into superuser?

Comment: @kelalaka I was tied between the two to be honest. If the mods think it's better suited over on superuser then that's fine by me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is that the private key contains the certificate and additional information...

Sorry, that's not correct.

In asymmetric key files a private key contains the public key (or, for DSA, enough data to rebuild the public key), but a certificate is a completely different beast altogether.

A certificate is A) a public key, B) some information about the owner of the public key, C) some information about who is attesting this information is true (enough), D) the signature from (C).

Once you have a certificate you can only use it in things like TLS when you also have the private key, but you need both parts, neither the "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" portion nor the "BEGIN PRIVATE KEY" portion can produce the other.  (Well, with enough (quantum) computing power you could recover the private key from a cert, but that's considered "infeasibly hard").

> I need to produce a public certificate from this private key.

You can produce a self-signed cert from the key via a command like

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key private.key -out new.cer
```

If you need it to be a trusted certificate, you'd create a certification request ("certificate signing request", CSR) and submit it to a CA.

```
openssl req -new -key private.key -out new.csr
```

Comment: For completeness, if you get a cert from a 'real' CA (e.g. Digicert, GoDaddy, LetsEncrypt) it will almost always need one or sometimes a few **'chain' cert(s)** to be validated, and _some_ applications notably TLS (and HTTPS) require the prover (server) to _send_ such chain cert(s). As a result there are hundreds of Qs across several Stacks on the themes of: What does 'missing chain cert(s)' mean? What are chain certs? How do I find/get my chain cert(s)? How do I configure this server with my chain cert(s)?

Comment: thanks @bartonjs - I clearly got my information about private keys and certs mixed up. thanks for the clarity.